# Why AngularJS ui-route is not working on android platform for cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I have a project which utilizes Ionic.io, Cordova and AngularJS. It works nicely on my computer Chrome browser, when I launch it with "ionic serve" on the command prompt. However, when I launch it to my connected android device with "ionic run", all I get is a blank screen. It was supposed to load a login screen. Here is the code:

This is the app.js file

```
// Ionic Starter App

    // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
    // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
    // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
    var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers'])

    app.run(function($ionicPlatform, $interval) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      });
      $interval(function(){}, 1000);
    })

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

      $stateProvider
       .state('home',
       {
        url: '/home',
        views:
        {
          'main_view':
          {
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'appCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
       .state('login',
       {
        url: '/login',
        views:
        {
          'main_view':
          {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
       .state('contact',
       {
        url: '/contact',
        views:
        {
          'main_view':
          {
            templateUrl: 'contact.html',
            controller: 'contactCtrl'
          }
        }
      });


      $stateProvider
       .state('home.timeline',
       {
        url: '/timeline',
        views:
        {
          'timeline_tab':
          {
            templateUrl: 'home_items.html',
            controller: 'timelineCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
       .state('home.news',
       {
        url: '/news',
        views:
        {
          'news_tab':
          {
            templateUrl: 'home_items.html',
            controller: 'newsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
       .state('home.bulletins',
       {
        url: '/bulletins',
        views:
        {
          'bulletins_tab':
          {
            templateUrl: 'home_items.html',
            controller: 'bulletinsCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
       .state('home.requests',
       {
        url: '/requests',
        views:
        {
          'requests_tab':
          {
            templateUrl: 'home_items.html',
            controller: 'requestsCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

This is the index.html file, which was supposed to run all the content of the application, starting with the login screen and then changing to the other content screens when logged in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <!--<base href="http://www.comunicafacil.net/">-->

    <!-- inject:js --><script src="js/api/models/User.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Request.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/News.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Image.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Bulletin.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Area.js"></script><script src="js/vendor/md5.js"></script><script src="js/api/ComunicaFacilAPI.js"></script><script src="js/api/ComunicaFacil.js"></script><!-- endinject -->

    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    this is the only text that will be displayed on the app screen
      <ion-nav-view name="main_view">

      </ion-nav-view>
    </body>
```

The cordova version I'm using is 5.4.1, my device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab II, with Android 4.1.2.
Is there anything I need to change to allow the use of ui-route on android?
Is there any other piece of code needed here to identify the issue?

Comment: I would add in info about version of Cordova you are using, device/emulator and what version of OS you are testing on.

Comment: Please have a look at [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) to benefit from **remote debugging on a device**. Then your are able to get more detailed information about what is working wrong unless you are already using it...

Comment: @Beat this is very nice, I did not know about that, but I think I cannot do this with cordova applications.

Comment: I am working 24/7 this way and it works! ;-)

Comment: @MorrisonChang the cordova version is 5.4.1, my device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab II, with Android 4.1.2. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Beat Can I really debug "native" cordova applications with Chrome?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/next/#link-14), unfortunately you need at least `Android KitKat 4.4`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your 
     `<!-- inject:js --><script src="js/api/models/User.js"></script><script     src="js/api/models/Request.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/News.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Image.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Bulletin.js"></script><script src="js/api/models/Area.js"></script><script src="js/vendor/md5.js"></script><script src="js/api/ComunicaFacilAPI.js"></script><script src="js/api/ComunicaFacil.js"></script><!-- endinject -->`

After  `<script src="js/controller.js"></script>`

The white screen can be caused by any number of issues - as suggested you might want to use remote debugging with chrome (it's awesome btw) to work our whats wrong. You can also use `ionic run -l` and then type `c` to get the logs and see the error that way (phone and computer need to be on same wifi network).

My guess here is that your code is bombing on the device because "angular is undefined" or something similar (the order matters!)

Comment: thanks for the hint. Sadly, changing the order didn't do much. I don't have a post 4.4 android device, so I'll try to get me one and debug it with crhome.